# Extra characters at the end of filenames I create

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, yasm

I am attempting to learn assembler and am having an issue with this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_file_management.htm

it works fine and dandy except for when it writes out the file.  Instead of `myfile.txt`, it is named `myfile.txtWelcome to Tutorials PointWritten to file?`.

I can't seem to find out why. I took the source off the tutorial and it does the same thing.

Can someone tell me why?

---

I am using nasm 2.12.02. I have also tried it on yasm 1.2.0 so I am pretty sure it's the assembler code causing it.

I am building and running on `OpenSUSE Linux 3.16.7-35-default #1 SMP Sun Feb 7 17:32:21 UTC 2016 (832c776) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: You need to include your code in the body of your question.

Comment: @Laurel: Actually, the problem is obvious from the symptoms, even without seeing the code or looking at the tutorial.  But yes, this would be a much better question with the code included.  The title is also total garbage, since it doesn't describe the problem at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably left out a `, 0` (zero byte) to terminate the string in the `.rodata` section where you put the string constants you're using for file names and file data.

Linux system calls (like `open(2)`) that take `char*` args accept zero-terminated C-style strings, instead of accepting a string length.

Comment: Just looked at the tutorial. It has `section .data
file_name db 'myfile.txt'
msg db 'Welcome to Tutorials Point'`, i.e no zero delimiter anywhere. Pretty poor, since that means they probably didn't test their own code.

Comment: ... or they were lucky and some alignment option added a few zero bytes inbetween.

Comment: Thanks, i will add a null terminator and report back and it does sound like the culprit. Do you know of any better tutorials out there?

Comment: @Tyson: The [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has a couple links, but it's not something I've gone looking for, since I already know asm.  I have had a look at "Programming from the Ground Up", and I think it looks quite good, and teaches useful concepts / understanding.  It uses AT&T syntax, not NASM, but it's 32-bit x86 on Linux.  See the tag wiki for links to HTML and PDF versions of the free book.

Comment: Adding a null terminator worked. Not sure why I didn't see that, I actually wondered about that but it didn't dawn on me; I have coded in C in the past but now mainly use managed languages like C# so am rusty on the intricacies of C.

Comment: @Tyson: I wouldn't feel too bad; if you follow a tutorial and get the wrong results, it's normal to assume *you* did something wrong, not that the tutorial author has betrayed you by posting untested buggy code in their tutorial.  It's not even like they used something that would have worked in an older version of a language; that code was just always broken.